# XCode UI tests fail due to 'incomplete metadata'

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, appkit, xcuitest

I am trying to run UI tests for my cocoa macOS application. However when running the following test that checks the launch performance of my application, the tests fails every time:

```swift
func testLaunchPerformance() throws {
    if #available(macOS 10.15, *) {
        // This measures how long it takes to launch your application.
        measure(metrics: [XCTOSSignpostMetric.applicationLaunch]) {
            XCUIApplication().launch()
        }
    }
}
```

The following error message is printed. I guess it is saying that my app doesn't have complete metadata on one of the multiple launches of the app?!

```
2020-05-07 10:15:44.666665+0200 SkipItUITests-Runner[6288:100036] *** Assertion failure in -[SkipItUITests.SkipItUITests measureWithMetrics:options:block:], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/XCTest/XCTest-16091/Sources/XCTestFramework/Core/XCTestCase.m:1280
    t =    12.68s Assertion Failure: SkipItUITests.swift:38: failed: caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "Iteration with index 1 doesn't have complete metadata. metricIdentifier: com.apple.dt.XCTMetric_OSSignpost-ApplicationLaunchExtended.duration metricDisplayName: OS Signpost Duration (ApplicationLaunchExtended) measurementForIteration: (null)"
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff34c91d07 __exceptionPreprocess + 250
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6d9b55bf objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff34cbaec8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff373a5f3d -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
    4   XCTest                              0x0000000100275b0f -[XCTestCase measureWithMetrics:options:block:] + 3518
    5   XCTest                              0x0000000100274d28 -[XCTestCase measureWithMetrics:block:] + 111
    6   SkipItUITests                       0x0000000103ac5156 $s13SkipItUITestsAAC21testLaunchPerformanceyyKF + 422
    7   SkipItUITests                       0x0000000103ac539a $s13SkipItUITestsAAC21testLaunchPerformanceyyKFTo + 74
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff34bf7a6c __invoking___ + 140
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff34bf7911 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 303
    10  XCTest                              0x0000000100270f02 __24-[XCTestCase invokeTest]_block_invoke_3 + 52
    11  XCTest                              0x0000000100338ec1 +[XCTSwiftErrorObservation observeErrorsInBlock:] + 69
    12  XCTest                              0x0000000100270e04 __24-[XCTestCase invokeTest]_block_invoke_2 + 119
    13  XCTest                              0x00000001002fea3a -[XCTMemoryChecker _assertInvalidObjectsDeallocatedAfterScope:] + 51
    14  XCTest                              0x000000010027c696 -[XCTestCase assertInvalidObjectsDeallocatedAfterScope:] + 116
    15  XCTest                              0x0000000100270d5e __24-[XCTestCase invokeTest]_block_invoke.206 + 213
    16  XCTest                              0x00000001002e6563 +[XCTestCase(Failures) performFailableBlock:testCase:testCaseRun:shouldInterruptTest:] + 69
    17  XCTest                              0x00000001002e6474 -[XCTestCase(Failures) _performTurningExceptionsIntoFailuresInterruptAfterHandling:block:] + 115
    18  XCTest                              0x00000001002707f4 -[XCTestCase invokeTest] + 1144
    19  XCTest                              0x000000010027214f __26-[XCTestCase performTest:]_block_invoke_2 + 43
    20  XCTest                              0x00000001002e6563 +[XCTestCase(Failures) performFailableBlock:testCase:testCaseRun:shouldInterruptTest:] + 69
    21  XCTest                              0x00000001002e6474 -[XCTestCase(Failures) _performTurningExceptionsIntoFailuresInterruptAfterHandling:block:] + 115
    22  XCTest                              0x0000000100272086 __26-[XCTestCase performTest:]_block_invoke.366 + 86
    23  XCTest                              0x00000001002f650e +[XCTContext runInContextForTestCase:block:] + 211
    24  XCTest                              0x000000010027193a -[XCTestCase performTest:] + 566
    25  XCTest                              0x00000001002c53f5 -[XCTest runTest] + 57
    26  XCTest                              0x000000010026bc9b __27-[XCTestSuite performTest:]_block_invoke + 354
    27  XCTest                              0x000000010026b424 __59-[XCTestSuite _performProtectedSectionForTest:testSection:]_block_invoke + 24
    28  XCTest                              0x00000001002f650e +[XCTContext runInContextForTestCase:block:] + 211
    29  XCTest                              0x000000010026b3db -[XCTestSuite _performProtectedSectionForTest:testSection:] + 148
    30  XCTest                              0x000000010026b709 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 348
    31  XCTest                              0x00000001002c53f5 -[XCTest runTest] + 57
    32  XCTest                              0x000000010026bc9b __27-[XCTestSuite performTest:]_block_invoke + 354
    33  XCTest                              0x000000010026b424 __59-[XCTestSuite _performProtectedSectionForTest:testSection:]_block_invoke + 24
    34  XCTest                              0x00000001002f650e +[XCTContext runInContextForTestCase:block:] + 211
    35  XCTest                              0x000000010026b3db -[XCTestSuite _performProtectedSectionForTest:testSection:] + 148
    36  XCTest                              0x000000010026b709 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 348
    37  XCTest                              0x00000001002c53f5 -[XCTest runTest] + 57
    38  XCTest                              0x000000010026bc9b __27-[XCTestSuite performTest:]_block_invoke + 354
    39  XCTest                              0x000000010026b424 __59-[XCTestSuite _performProtectedSectionForTest:testSection:]_block_invoke + 24
    40  XCTest                              0x00000001002f650e +[XCTContext runInContextForTestCase:block:] + 211
    41  XCTest                              0x000000010026b3db -[XCTestSuite _performProtectedSectionForTest:testSection:] + 148
    42  XCTest                              0x000000010026b709 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 348
    43  XCTest                              0x00000001002c53f5 -[XCTest runTest] + 57
    44  XCTest                              0x00000001003117dd __44-[XCTTestRunSession runTestsAndReturnError:]_block_invoke + 171
    45  XCTest                              0x00000001003118c3 __44-[XCTTestRunSession runTestsAndReturnError:]_block_invoke.100 + 96
    46  XCTest                              0x000000010029351b -[XCTestObservationCenter _observeTestExecutionForBlock:] + 692
    47  XCTest                              0x0000000100311567 -[XCTTestRunSession runTestsAndReturnError:] + 615
    48  XCTest                              0x000000010024ee36 -[XCTestDriver runTestsAndReturnError:] + 458
    49  XCTest                              0x00000001002f2231 _XCTestMain + 2485
    50  SkipItUITests-Runner                0x0000000100001dba _XCTRunnerRunTests + 258
    51  SkipItUITests-Runner                0x0000000100001cb8 _XCTRunnerRunTests + 0
    52  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff6eb5ccc9 start + 1
)
    t =    12.79s Tear Down
Test Case '-[SkipItUITests.SkipItUITests testLaunchPerformance]' failed (12.792 seconds).
Test Suite 'SkipItUITests' failed at 2020-05-07 10:15:44.831.
     Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (1 unexpected) in 12.792 (12.793) seconds
Test Suite 'SkipItUITests.xctest' failed at 2020-05-07 10:15:44.831.
     Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (1 unexpected) in 12.792 (12.793) seconds
Test Suite 'Selected tests' failed at 2020-05-07 10:15:44.832.
     Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (1 unexpected) in 12.792 (12.794) seconds
```

How can I fix the test case such that it is successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so apparently something was wrong with my project setup. I created a new project and copied my files over into the new project and now the UI tests run through.

Answer (score 0):

Moving `os_signpost(.end)` into `DispatchQueue.main.async` worked for me when using with XCTest with `XCTOSSignpostMetrict`.